# Resave imported data with same header lines in matlab

Tags: matlab

Good day,

I am importing a text data file into matlab 'Old_file.p2m'

The data file has the first two lines as a header, as shown below:

data Set
Rx     X(m)   Y(m)   RSS(dBm)
1        10         20      -76.71
2        15         20      -76.64
3        20         20      -76.57

So I am using the following code to import the data:

**filename =('Old_file.p2m');
tmp = importdata(filename,' ',2);**

Which specifies that the first two are header lines and reads the data into a 1x1 struct 'tmp'.

Now, I have the first 2 header lines in tmp.textdata and the remaining numeric data in column format in tmp.data

My question is that after I modify a column of tmp.data, how can I resave the modified struct into another file New_file.p2m with the same header file appended on top of it (basically the same format as the Old_file.p2m).

I tried using:

save('New_file.p2m','-struct','tmp');

but the newly saved file New_file.p2m is unreadable gibberish.

Any suggestions?

Comment: first try adding '-ascii' to the save command. Default is some proprietary binary format, which will look like gibberish.

Comment: Yup, tried that, the new file is now empty.

Comment: hmmm. '-ascii' doesn't support all data types - but shouldn't be empty. Maybe the '-struct' is problematic. Anyway, I think the fwrite solution is far more superior. So better research on that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [fwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html). This function allow you to right data in the order you want, and maybe you can do your loading with fread as well.